# Android - how to get the pdf file size through url?

Tags: java, android

My program will be crushed when I run these methods

I want to get the pdf file length as a String and set this text on TextView

```
private String getSize(String url1){
    URL url = null;
    try {  
       url = new URL(url1);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
       URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
       connection = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final int length = connection.getContentLength();
    String size = "" + length;
    return size;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "will be crushed"? Does it crash? If so, please provide the Stacktrace / Error whatever.
If You run into the catch block, then connection will still be `null` - therefore `connection.getContentLength()`  will produce a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to get file size:

```
URL url = new URL("http://testserver.com/file.pdf");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
int fileSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

textView.setText(String.valueOf(fileSize));
```

Comment: i found my app crash because of [urlConnection.getContentLength();]. i have no ideas what am i suppose to do.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `URLConnection.getContentLength()` as below.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://your_url.com/filename.pdf");
    final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    final int length = connection.getContentLength();
    Log.d(tag, String.valueof(length));
```

Your Answer:-

```
private String getSize(String url1){
    URL url = null;
    try {  
       url = new URL(url1);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
       URLConnection connection = null;
    try {
       connection = url.openConnection();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final int length = connection.getContentLength();
    String size = "" + String.valueof(length);
    return size;
}
```

Remember to give INTERNET permission in menifest :-

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```